# How to build Rust Email sender with different Email login

Tags: rust, tauri

I am trying to create a mailer through Tauri backend using Rust.
I have been using Lettre as the sender of the email.
Using starttls through the outlook server works fine until I try to use an input converted to a string as the credentials. Then it get

I want to be able to open the app, and login using different emails. This is intended to be shared and used across several people.

Here is the specific chunk of Rust code I have attached to a React button:

Minimal Reproducible Copy:
-Create New Tauri App
-App.jsx

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { invoke } from '@tauri-apps/api/tauri';

function startpage() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  function loginOutlook() {
    const emailString = JSON.stringify(email);
    const passwordString = JSON.stringify(password);
    
    invoke('take2_send_test_email_with_login_info', {invoke_message: emailString, invoke_message2: passwordString});

  }
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h2>Please enter your Outlook login info here</h2>
      <label>
        Enter Email: 
        <input 
          name="email" 
          type="text"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>

      <label>
        Enter Password: 
        <input 
          type="password" 
          name="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
       />
      </label>
      
      <button
        onClick={
          () => {
            loginOutlook()
          }
        }
      >
        Send Test Email
      </button>

      <a href="/fileimport">
      <button>
        Next
      </button>
      </a>
    </div>
  )
}

export default startpage
```

```
use lettre::message::header::ContentType;
use lettre::transport::smtp::authentication::Credentials;
use lettre::{
  Message, SmtpTransport, Transport,
};

use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

async fn take2_send_test_email_with_login_info(invoke_message: String, invoke_message2: String){
  
  println!("Take 2 Send Test email");
  let login_info = EmailLoginInfo { 
    email_string: String::from(invoke_message), 
    password_string: String::from(invoke_message2)
  };

  let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&login_info).unwrap();
  let deserialized: EmailLoginInfo = serde_json::from_str(&serialized).unwrap();

  let deserialized_email = deserialized.email_string;
  let deserialized_password = deserialized.password_string;

  let email = Message::builder()
  .from("Test Outlook From <testOutlookFrom@example.com>".parse().unwrap())
  .to("Test Outlook From <testOutlookTo@example.com>".parse().unwrap())
  .subject("Rust")
  .header(ContentType::TEXT_PLAIN)
  .body(String::from("Test"))
  .unwrap();

  let creds = Credentials::new(deserialized_email.to_owned(),deserialized_password.to_owned());
  //What works:  
  //let creds = Credentials::new("smtpEmail".to_owned(),"smtpPassword".to_owned());
  // Open a remote connection to Outlook servers
  let mailer = SmtpTransport::starttls_relay("smtp.office365.com")
    .unwrap()
    .credentials(creds)
    .build();

  // Send the email
  match mailer.send(&email) {
    Ok(_) => println!("Email sent successfully!"),
    Err(e) => println!("Could not send email: {e:?}"),
  }
}
```

The error I keep receiving when clicking the button:
`Could not send email: lettre::transport::smtp::Error { kind: Permanent(Code { severity: PermanentNegativeCompletion, category: Unspecified3, detail: Five }), source: "5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [MW4PR04CA0316.namprd04.prod.outlook.com 2023-09-11T15:05:52.851Z 08DBB23E809652C4]" }`

Comment: How are the user credentials retrieved? The problem is likely there. You need to provide a complete [mre] for us to identify the problem.

Comment: Wait, why do you take your string parameters, put them in a struct, serialize it, deserialize it, and get those fields back out? Those ten lines look absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: @kmdreko using the Rust wiki, it recommended using seriliaze to create structs. as for the putting it in, and feeding it back out, that was my just testing each step of the way

Comment: @E_net4 i have added the necessary front-end information, if i need to provide a github link I can, it is just a mess.

Comment: I suspect `JSON.stringify` is adding additional quotes to your email and password.

Answer (score 0):

@kmdreko provided some helpful insight.

It was not a RUST issue, I was using JSON Stringify on my strings, and that was adding an extra quotation set that was messing up the code.

Added a quick line, and fixed it.

```
    const emailStringJSON = JSON.stringify(email);
    const passwordStringJSON = JSON.stringify(password);

    const emailString = emailStringJSON.slice(1,-1);
    const passwordString = passwordStringJSON.slice(1,-1);
```

Comment: You should just be able to `invoke` with `{ invoke_message: email, invoke_message2: password }`. The `JSON.stringify` and slicing should not be necessary at all.

Comment: Why is JSONifying anything necessary here unless you're using JSON as a transport encoding? It's especially bizarre that you encode, then strip off the encoding quotes.